# Deleting randomly generated strings as the loop keeps executing

Tags: java, string, random, stringbuilder

The code below is written to generate 5 random Strings consisting of X's and O's for 9 character spaces. When printing the strings, the strings keep adding onto the previous string and becomes long. How do I get the strings to print on a new line every time its generated?

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    Random r = new Random();
    String subset = "XO";
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            int index = r.nextInt(subset.length());
            char c = subset.charAt(index);
            b.append(c);
        }
        String s = b.toString() ;

        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to move your stringBuilder initialization inside your first for loop. That way, it will delete the characters already on it instead of just appending them to the end. Essentially your stringBuilder never resets to be empty.

Comment: Hey Thank you so much! Also, do you know how I can restrict the number of "X"'s and "O"s within the 9 characters? For example, in a tictactoe board, you'd expect 5 X's and 4 O's or 5 O's and 4 X's...

Comment: You could count up the number of X's (or O's) at the end, and if it's not 4 or 5, then just throw out the string. To have it run again as if there was no effect, you could subtract one from your iterative variable `i`, and only let it print if it meets your restrictions.

Comment: Hi I tried to restrict them the way you said, but i don't think i'm doing it correctly, because when i run the program it still allows Strings with 6"X"s to pass through

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to programming...

int counter_X = 0; 
int counter_O = 0; 
for (int k = 0; k < s.length(); k++) { 
    if (s.charAt(i) == 'X') { 
 counter_X++; 
    } 
    else if (s.charAt(i) == 'O') { 
        counter_O++; } 
    } 
    if (counter_X != 5 || counter_O != 4) { 
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(s);
 sb.delete(0, 9); 
}

Comment: Yes, a silly mistake! So I should place this code right after the 

System.out.println(s); 

statement right? Thanks so much btw~

Comment: Hmm, before, right? You want to check if your string is valid, and then if it is you print.

Comment: oh yeah, I put it before the print statement.. it's still accepting strings with less than 4 X's

Comment: It would be better to put either 5 X's and 4 O's (or 5 O's and 4 X's) into a list and call `Collections.shuffle` on it, and then add those items to the `StringBuilder`. Better still, ask new questions in new questions instead of in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Your `StringBuilder` is never reinitialized. You can either move the

```
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
```

line right after

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
```

or add the line

```
b.setLength(0);
```

after the line

```
String s = b.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
Random random = new Random();

List<String> chars = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
  chars.add("X");
  chars.add("O");
}

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
  Collections.shuffle(chars);
  builder.delete(0, builder.length());
  for (String charStr : chars)
  {
    builder.append(charStr);
  }

  if(random.nextBoolean())
  {
    builder.append("X");
  }
  else{
    builder.append("O");
  }

  System.out.println(builder.toString());
}
```

Try not to initiate variables inside loops unless you really need to do it